# How to travel to the UK as a spouse of an EU citizen?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, family

I am an Indian citizen. I have a 3-year Polish TRC. I just got married to a Czech citizen.

We want to visit the UK. Is it possible to travel UK with my wife?

Comment: Can I travel without family member card with my wife

Answer (score 8):

You have to get either:

1. An Article 10 family member residence card.
2. An EEA Family Permit (free 6-month UK visa)

With one of these, you can enter the UK together with your wife

Comment: I have polish resident card  but my wife   is eu  citizen can I travel ireland together without entry visa I don't have eu  family member card

Comment: @Sayedzohib Yes, you can use your passport and EU family member card (that's what's called an Article 10 card)

Comment: I don't have  eu  family  member card I have polish visa

Comment: I don't have eu  family member card

Comment: @Sayedzohib Then you need a visa (called EEA family permit)

Comment: How I can apply eea family permit if we both not have work

Comment: @Sayedzohib You don't need that; as a family member of an EU citizen you have the legal right to enter the UK. Just submit documentation proving your relationship, and you'll get the visa

Comment: @Sayedzohib You can also choose to get the EU family member card, if she's a Czech citizen but you both live in Poland. THen you don't need the visa

Comment: She lives in czech republic  and I live in poland we met 2 time in the month .now we can't afford home to live together .and I don't how to apply in poland .how I can start process